# C++ segment fault error

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

Hi I have an array object in my header file.

```
private:
Customer** customerListArray;
```

Then in my CPP file I set the array size and add objects as following,

```
void AppManager::createArrays(vector<vector<string> > data) {

    customerListArray = new Customer* [data.size()];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){

        try {

            Customer* cust = createCustomerObject(data[i]);
            customerListArray[i] = cust;
        }
        catch(string err) {

            cout << "Error processing line '" << i << "' of data file. Error Message : " << err << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Size of data vector is about 14000 items. However when I loop through customerListArray and print items I get the following error,

```
C5545 - Burton G. Craft - 3/1/14
C5546 - Zena F. Wallace - 10/2/14
C5547 - Ursa P. Orr - 20/4/14
C5548 - Adara X. Rogers - 3/6/13
C5549 - Carter L. Newman - 15/1/14
C5550 - Maxwell V. Watkins - 5/6/13
C5551 - Ria V. Morrow - 8/12/12
C5552 - Kirk Z. Hines - 27/4/14
C5553 - Brent L. Bentley - 13/10/13
C5554 - Thane W. Cobb - 8/8/14
C5555 - Serina M. Macias - 13/8/13
C5556 - Maryam J. Lynch - 1/6/13
C5557 - Breanna M. Lewis - 20/10/13
Segmentation fault
```

It always crashes at item C5557 with a Segmentation fault. When I use a vector it works all fine. but my requirement is to use an array by the assignment.

Please advise :)

Thank you.

Edit:

```
vector<vector<string> > data= fileReader(customerFile);
data= customerVals.size(); //about 14000 records

//debug priting
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numOfCustomers; i++) {
      Customer* cust = customerListArray[i];
      cout << cust->getCustomerId() << " - " << cust->getName() << " - " << cust->getDateLastPurchased()->getDay() << "/" << cust->getDateLastPurchased()->getMonth() << "/" << cust->getDateLastPurchased()->getYear() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: What is `data.size()`, and what is `i` when the program crashes?  Add a few prints.

Comment: Probably need to show the loop you use for printing - after all it is where the crash occurs.

Comment: Are you checking for `NULL` before printing?

Comment: Updated :) the creation of the loop and printing

Comment: @SB - do'h! I forgot to check for null, thank you so much, element 5558 never gets added to the array because of an exception and thus it's null!

Comment: where do you set numOfCustomers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do'h! I forgot to check for null, thank you so much, element 5558 never gets added to the array because of an exception and thus it's null!

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numOfCustomers; i++) {

        Customer* cust = customerListArray[i];
        if(cust != NULL) {

            cout << cust->getCustomerId() << " - " << cust->getName() << " - " << cust->getDateLastPurchased()->getDay() << "/" << cust->getDateLastPurchased()->getMonth() << "/" << cust->getDateLastPurchased()->getYear() << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Checking for NULL fixed it problem!

Comment: Is this release or debug build? I would expect that in release build, in case of exception, the pointer would be uninitialized and had some garbage value. It would not be NULL but would not point to valid object either. I think you should set it explicitly to NULL in the `catch` block.